# The obligations of the knight

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, ecclesiastical-latin, christianity

I was studying the order of knights os St. John and found the 8 obligations or aspirations of a Knight, they are:

1. to live in truth
2. to have faith
3. repent one's sins
4. give proof of humility
5. love justice
6. be merciful
7. be sincere and wholehearted
8. to endure persecution

But knowing that the order was under the church, I believe that it was originally written in Latin
So, when I translated from English to Latin I realized that I might be translating something that was originally written in that language

The translation I got is:

1. vivere in veritate
2. habere fidem
3. poenitere peccata
4. humilitatis indicium
5. amare iustitiam
6. esto misericors
7. sitis sinceri et in corde perfecto
8. persecutionem pati

I'm still researching everywhere, but so far I couldn't find how the original text was written
But is this translation in accordance with the Latin of that time?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for an answer that specifically touches upon only these obligations, or what the historical Latin obligations are for the Knights? It's a deep rabbit hole, apparently.

Comment: @cmw, I believe he wants to know if this looks like ecclesiastic latin, or if this looks like an official document written in the Church's Latin.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças, Yes, that's what I want!

Comment: Given the quality and type of sources for the "obligations or aspirations of a knight" that Google returns, I doubt a medieval origin. However, the Order of Malta itself [lists](https://www.orderofmalta.int/history/the-eight-pointed-cross/) "eight virtues that a member of the Order must possess."